# How to validate if a GCP PubSub Topic has write access using the service account in java?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I have a service account say for Project A which has write access to the Pubsub topic defined in Project B. I want to validate the same programatically? Could Anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have IAM permissions to Project B? If not, you cannot.

Comment: In which langage do you want to perform the check? Do you know exactly which permission, or role, that you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself.
Here is the sample code

```
public static void PubSubTopicValidator(String projectId, String topicId)
    throws IOException {

    TopicAdminSettings topicAdminSettings = getTopicAdminSettings(projectId);

    try (TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create(topicAdminSettings)) {
        ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicId);

        List<String> permissions = new LinkedList<>();
        permissions.add("pubsub.topics.attachSubscription");
        permissions.add("pubsub.topics.publish");
        permissions.add("pubsub.topics.update");

        TestIamPermissionsRequest testIamPermissionsRequest =
            TestIamPermissionsRequest.newBuilder()
                .setResource(topicName.toString())
                .addAllPermissions(permissions)
                .build();

        TestIamPermissionsResponse testedPermissionsResponse = topicAdminClient.testIamPermissions(testIamPermissionsRequest);

        log.info("Tested:\n" + testedPermissionsResponse);


    }
}

private static TopicAdminSettings getTopicAdminSettings(String projectId) throws IOException {
    log.info("Get Topic admin settings ");
    String defaultProjectId = System.getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT");
    GoogleCredentials credentials;
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("int_sa.json");

    log.info(" inputstream "+ is);
    if(projectId.equals(defaultProjectId)){
        credentials = getDefaultCredentials();
    }
    else{
        credentials = getGoogleCredentials(is);
    }

    return TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                 .build();
}
```